# Strange painting bug in GraphicsView in PyQt 5.7

Tags: qt, pyqt5

[updating with smaller example]

We just upgraded to PyQt 5.7 and we have one the last problem left to fix in our application. Here is a standalone example that I created from our application code. Run it and see how the ellipse gets drawn beyond the view borders. This did not occur in 5.5.1. Platform is Windows 7 64 bit (running in a VM). It looks like this:

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsProxyWidget, QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsEllipseItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush


class MyGraphicsItem(QGraphicsObject):

    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsObject.__init__(self)

        # next line could be any type of graphics item:
        rect_item = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 100, 100, self)
        # effect easier to see if paint black:
        rect_item.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.SolidPattern))

        label_item = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)
        # *** Next line must be there for effect to be visible, but could be any other type of widget
        label_item.setWidget(QLabel('a'*30))

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        return

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()


def show_problem():
    app = QApplication([])

    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view.setScene(scene)

    scene.addItem(MyGraphicsItem())  # *** effect only there if more than 1 item
    scene.addItem(MyGraphicsItem())

    layout.addWidget(view)

    widget.setGeometry(100, 100, 50, 50)
    widget.show()
    app.exec()


show_problem()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Russell confirmed that [this is a regression in 5.7](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-September/038034.html) (i.e., problem was not present in PyQt 5.6).

I posted a C++ version of my Python example to Qt Forum. A fellow there was kind enough to fix compilation bugs and run it, and saw the bug: so this is indeed a Qt bug.

There is a [bug report at bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55070) that is almost certainly the same issue. It is not resolved, but by an incredible luck, it links to a post [where there is a workaround](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/66485-Qt-5-7-QGraphicsObject-paint-issue?p=292754#post292754): set the opacity of proxy widget item to just below 1. In the example app of my post, I added

```
label_item.setOpacity(0.999999)
```

after setting label_item's widget. I our real app (110k PyQt code) I set the opacity of all QGraphicsProxyWidget instance and it seems to work.

This workaround seems to not have any other side effects, time will tell if there are deeper problems. But it appears to be at least be a temporary solution until the bug gets fixed in Qt. I have submitted a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55918).

Comment: Schollii, thank you for your workaround. Please, could you follow up the bug report, since they are asking a minimum working example? They have closed the issue until your reply.

Comment: @lopital I'd love to but this past while I have not had access to a c++ dev env on Windows AND spare time, just one or the other. :(.